# How are outer classes associated with inner classes in java?

Tags: java, oop

I know each instance of an inner class in java is associated with an instance of its outer class, but I am wondering how this process goes about.

More specifically, when you write something like

```java
public class Outer {
    Inner root;

    class Inner {
        public Inner() {
             next = (Math.random() > 0.5)? new Inner(): null;
        }

        Inner next;
    }
}
```

How are `root`, `root.next`, etc... all associated with the same instance of `Outer`? Does the compiler add a parameter to the Inner constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are root, root.next, etc... all associated with the same instance
>   of `Outer`?

The [Java Language Specification section on Determining Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2) during class instance creation states:

> **Let `C` be the class being instantiated, and let `i` be the instance being created**. If `C` is an inner class, then `i` may have an immediately enclosing instance (§8.1.3), determined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - **If `C` is an inner member class**, then:
>
>   - If the class instance creation expression is **unqualified**, then:
>
>     > - If the class instance creation expression occurs in a static context, then a compile-time error occurs.
>     > - Otherwise, if **`C` is a member of a class enclosing the class in which the class instance creation expression appears**, then let `O` be the immediately enclosing class of which `C` is a member. Let `n` be an integer such that `O` is the n'th lexically enclosing type declaration of the class in which the class instance creation expression appears.
>     >
>     >   **The immediately enclosing instance of `i` is the n'th lexically enclosing instance of `this`**.
>     > - Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

In other words, when you perform

```
next = (Math.random() > 0.5)? new Inner(): null;
```

`Inner` is the class being instantiated; `Inner` is a member of a class enclosing the class (`Inner`, ie. itself) where the `new Inner()` appears; `Outer` is the immediately enclosing class of `Inner`; because `Inner` is an inner class of `Outer`, there has to be a `this` and that `this` is guaranteed to have an `Outer` enclosing instance; and, finally, that enclosing instance becomes the enclosing instance of `i`, the new `Inner` instance being created.

In short, it reuses the same instance of `Outer`.

> Does the compiler add a parameter to the `Inner` constructor?

The [Java Language Specification section on the Formal Parameters of Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.1) states:

> The constructor of a non-private inner member class implicitly
>   declares, as the first formal parameter, a variable representing the
>   immediately enclosing instance of the class (§15.9.2, §15.9.3).

So, yes.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what happens differently when the class is private? The section on formal parameters doesn't seem to say.

Comment: @SimonBerens Behavior doesn't change. (Or please clarify that question.)

Comment: It's just it says "The constructor of a non-private ..." so I was assuming there is different behaviour for a private inner member class.

Comment: @SimonBerens Sorry, I thought you were referring to the reuse of the enclosing instance. The link before the quote has further explanation of why it's qualified that way. My understanding is that even with `private` member classes, a compiler will do so anyway, but it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

First note that Java does not have any support for inner classes so actually Inner class is compiled as a separate class. This is denoted as `Outer$Inner`. Here's the bytecode:

```
// class version 52.0 (52)
// access flags 0x20
class Outer$Inner {

  // compiled from: Outer.java
  // access flags 0x0
  INNERCLASS Outer$Inner Outer Inner

  // access flags 0x0
  LOuter$Inner; next

  // access flags 0x1010
  final synthetic LOuter; this$0

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>(LOuter;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 5 L0
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    PUTFIELD Outer$Inner.this$0 : LOuter;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L1
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Math.random ()D
    LDC 0.5
    DCMPL
    IFLE L2
    NEW Outer$Inner
    DUP
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESPECIAL Outer$Inner.<init> (LOuter;)V
    GOTO L3
   L2
   FRAME FULL [Outer$Inner Outer] [Outer$Inner]
    ACONST_NULL
   L3
   FRAME FULL [Outer$Inner Outer] [Outer$Inner Outer$Inner]
    PUTFIELD Outer$Inner.next : LOuter$Inner;
   L4
    LINENUMBER 7 L4
    RETURN
   L5
    LOCALVARIABLE this LOuter$Inner; L0 L5 0
    LOCALVARIABLE this$0 LOuter; L0 L5 1
    MAXSTACK = 5
    MAXLOCALS = 2
}
```

As you correctly guessed, the `Outer` class instance is passed to the constructor of the `Inner` class here `public <init>(LOuter;)V`